# “bamboo-java-specs” java is not creating docker image programmatically

Tags: java, docker, bamboo, docker-build, bamboo-specs

AS per bamboo- yml-specs, we cannot build a docker image.
So, I am trying to build a docker image by using “bamboo- java-specs”. But not able to create a docker image from it.
Please note that I have created a maven project and added bamboo-specs dependency to it. I am trying to create a docker image by using below code snippet.

```
  DockerBuildImageTask dockerBuildImageTask = new DockerBuildImageTask()
            .imageName("myapp")
            .dockerfileFromPath(Paths.get("Dockerfile"));
```

The code ran successfully with no error but I am unbale see myapp image created in docker desktop.
Please suggest what went wrong.

Comment: Did you run the plan? Do you have a DockerPushImageTask? Provide the source of the whole @BambooSpec-annotated class.

Comment: So Docker Desktop is running on the same host as the Bamboo agent? What does the log file from the build tell you?